# Python Logging Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have got a logging question in Python 3.7.x.

```
#logging_config_yaml_file

version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: "%(asctime)s || %(name)s || %(levelname)s || %(message)s"
handlers:
  console: # configuration for handler with id 'console' goes here
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  info_file_handler: # configuration for handler with id 'info_file_handler' goes here
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    filename: ./logs/db_update_info.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 20
    encoding: utf8
  rotate_file_handler2: # configuration for handler with id 'rotate_file_handler2' goes here
     class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
     level: DEBUG
     formatter: simple
     filename: ./logs/app_search_info.log
     maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
     backupCount: 20
     encoding: utf8
  rotate_file_handler3: # configuration for handler with id 'rotate_file_handler3' goes here
     class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
     level: DEBUG
     formatter: simple
     filename: ./logs/query_search_info.log
     maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
     backupCount: 20
     encoding: utf8
loggers:
  Trie_db:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [info_file_handler]
    propagate: False
  Trie_db.insert:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [rotate_file_handler2]
    propagate: False
  Trie_db.search:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [rotate_file_handler3]
    propagate: False
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

That’s my `logging yaml config` file, And I am using them as follows:

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger('Trie_db')
self.insertLogger = logging.getLogger('Trie_db.insert')
#sample line used to log is : t.insertLogger.debug(f'Insert used...blah blah')
self.searchLogger = logging.getLogger('Trie_db.search')
#sample line used to log is : t.searchLogger.info(f'Searched for...blah blah')
```

All good so far. Here comes the issue: it’s creating only the **two** log files, named:

- creates this **db_update_info.log** (one in the info_file_handler) and
- creates this **app_search_info.log** (one in the rotate_file_handler2)
  and
- **doesn't even create the third file** (**query_search_info.log**) (one in the rotate_file_handler3);

Rather when using the third one (`<same_class_obj>.searchLogger`), it’s writing the log messages to the file in the `db_update_info.log` and not in the one I had specified in `rotating_file_handler3` i.e. in `query_search_info.log`.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: It seems to work when I try it. Can you post a runnable example that demonstrates the problem? I had to make up an example, and since mine worked with the same configuration I wonder if there is something going on in the code we can't see...

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do the same, not sure because of copyright issues. Can you share how you used it(gist or something), that will help me fix the issue(s)! Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to share your *actual* code. Just example code that reproduces the problem when we run it.

Comment: Okay, i will try to create it and update back! Thanks.

Comment: Oh crap! How can i be so silly :(  it's working, it's just i messed up with the same file names, was editing a different yml and using a different yml! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to post code in a comment, so I'll post my example here and maybe you can spot where your code is different. I put your log configuration into a file named `logconfig.yml`, then ran the following code:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

logger = logging.getLogger('Trie_db')
insertLogger = logging.getLogger('Trie_db.insert')
searchLogger = logging.getLogger('Trie_db.search')

with open('logconfig.yml', 'r') as f:
    log_cfg = yaml.safe_load(f.read())

logging.config.dictConfig(log_cfg)

# I log to each logger at three different priorities just to make sure
# nothing is getting filtered.
for l in [logger, insertLogger, searchLogger]:
    l.debug('This is a debug message')
    l.info('This is an info message')
    l.warning('This is a warning message')
```

This results in three files in my `logs` directory:

```
$ ls logs
app_search_info.log  db_update_info.log  query_search_info.log
```

Which contain the expected information:

```
$ cat logs/app_search_info.log
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db.insert || DEBUG || This is a debug message
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db.insert || INFO || This is an info message
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db.insert || WARNING || This is a warning message
$ cat logs/db_update_info.log
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db || DEBUG || This is a debug message
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db || INFO || This is an info message
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db || WARNING || This is a warning message
$ cat logs/query_search_info.log
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db.search || DEBUG || This is a debug message
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db.search || INFO || This is an info message
2019-11-23 23:12:02,273 || Trie_db.search || WARNING || This is a warning message
```